# Ember.js bindAttr plus plaintext

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I bind an attribute and concatenate some plaintext with it?

For example:

```
<span {{bindAttr title="updates 'revisions'"}}>{{updates}} revisions</span>
```

To produce:

```
<span title="4 revisions">4 revisions</span>
```

Is there a way to do this without writing a new helper? I feel like I have to write a helper for every simple thing with Handlebars...

Answer (score 2):

You can add to you model new calculated field

```
App.Revisions = Em.Object.extend({
   updates:5,
   updatesTitle:function(){
     return this.get('updates') + ' revisions';
   }.property('updates'),
});
```

In Handlebars change to:

```
<span {{bindAttr title="updatesTitle"}}>{{updates}} revisions</span>
```

or

```
<span {{bindAttr title="updatesTitle"}}>{{updatesTitle}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll can defined it like this:

```
<span {{bindAttr title="updates :revisions"}}>{{updates}} revisions</span>
```

You can read more about it [in the docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/).

Comment: I think that may only work for booleans and class names.  I tried it with a label's 'for' property `{{ bindAttr for="id :appendThis" }}` and nothing was rendered in the 'for' property.  When I do `{{ bindAttr for=id }}`, the for property is set to the controller's 'id' property.